# Tensorflow - softmax with data of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am building a neural network model with data matrix of same number of columns(features) but varying number of rows, and hence varying size of training labels. I am using cross entropy with logit as the loss function.

For example, I have data like this:

```
data1 = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0.4,0.5]])
data2 = np.array([[0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0.4,0.5]])
label_1 = np.array([0,0,1])
label_2 = np.array([1,0])
```

so we have a weight vector of dimension (3x1) and a bias b, and our loss function is:

```
loss = -1*(log(label_1*softmax(data1*weight+b)) + log(label_2*softmax(data2*weight+b)))
```

In Tensorflow, I know I can define a placeholder with None dimension like:

```
tf_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, None, feature_size))
tf_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, None))
```

My question is, how can I feed the data to `feed_dict`? Since `data = np.array([data1,data2])` returns a numpy array storing two numpy arrays and result in:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

Also, what tensorflow function I can use to compute `data*weight? tf.matmul(data,weight)` result in Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your input data is a sequence and your output data is a sequence with as many elements as there are in the input sequence.

> My question is, how can I feed the data to feed_dict? Since data = np.array([data1,data2])

You get an error because the second dimension of `data_2` is smaller than the second dimension of `data_1`. You can pad `data_2` and `label_2` with zeros such that they have the same shape as `data_1` and `label_1` respectively.

Additionally you should define a mask placeholder to ensure that the padded part of `label_2` is not incorporated in the calculation of your loss function.

> so we have a weight vector of dimension (3x1)

This will not work. Your weight vector should have shape `(input_dim, output_dim)`. In this case you seem to have two dimensional inputs for which the second dimension varies. For this dimension you should take the maximal possible sequence length (as you will pad the smaller inputs to this value). The output dimension will also be the maximal sequence length. Say this is `4`, then shape of W should be: `(3, 4, 4)` and the shape of `b` should be `(4,)`.

> Also, what tensorflow function I can use to compute data*weight? tf.matmul(data,weight) result in Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'MatMul'

`tf.matmul` is correct. When data has shape `(batch_size, 3, 4)` and weight has shape `(3, 4, 4)`. The result will have shape `(batch_size, 4)`.

This is an updated version of your code (again assuming the maximum sequence length is `4`):

```
data1 = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0.4,0.5]])
data2 = np.array([[0.2,0.3,0.4],[0.3,0.4,0.5]])
data1_padded = np.concatenate([data1, np.zeros(shape=(1,3), dtype=np.float32)], 0)
data2_padded = np.concatenate([data2, np.zeros(shape=(2,3), dtype=np.float32)], 0)

label_1 = np.array([0,0,1.])
label_1_padded = np.concatenate([label_1, np.zeros(shape=(1), dtype=np.float32)], 0)
label_2 = np.array([1.,0])
label_2_padded = np.concatenate([label_2, np.zeros(shape=(2), dtype=np.float32)], 0)

mask_1 = np.array([1., 1., 0., 0.])
mask_2 = np.array([1., 1., 1., 0.])
```

That being said the network architecture you propose (feed-forward neural network) is not well suited for sequences. I suggest you take a look at recurrent neural networks and/or convolutional neural networks. The implementation will be similar as you are also required to do padding.